# What's the theoretical worst average centipawn loss on LiChess?

Tags: evaluation, lichess

Since mate is evaluated as a [finite centipawn loss](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/22087/2785), all games have a finite average centipawn loss.  I stumbled upon [this Reddit r/chess thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/mm8j00/my_friend_and_i_tried_to_get_the_highest_possible/) where [this game](https://lichess.org/Q08G2qqd#1) has an average centipawn loss of 1971 vs. 1981, but maybe it's possible to achieve a greater average centipawn loss.

**Question**: What's the theoretical worst average centipawn loss on LiChess?

Here I'm not interested in chess variants.

I imported [this game](https://lichess.org/UFHBl9ys) (adapted from the above) which gives an average centipawn loss of 1982 vs. 1988; here LiChess evaluated to move 150 (unlike the above game, where LiChess only evaluated to move 100 (although [it's still slightly better (1972 vs. 1982)](https://lichess.org/tLgqqIv6) when evaluated to 100 moves, since the queen is hanging on the 3rd ply)).

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: first comment on the reddit post says "Since ACPL caps at +-10, the max you can lose is 2000 centipawns per move and since the first few moves wont be +-2000, the final score will be <2000. Nonetheless, very cool"

Comment: Fascinating analysis graph - looks like the output of an oscilloscope!

Comment: Gotham Chess just uploaded [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QebVAG6l2ck) which place Stockfish's worst move each time.